# Flutter Downloader : Show message Dialog when file downloaded

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a file in db and user can download it by `flutter_downloader` package and its working fine. Now how can i display message to user after file download completed?

main file :

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
      debug: true // optional: set false to disable printing logs to console
      );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I want to show message when the file is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [flutter_file_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_downloader) it has the callback you want, it also has a progress listener

Usage example

```
FileDownloader.downloadFile(
    url: "https://tinypng.com/images/social/website.jpg",
    name: "PANDA",
    onProgress: (String? fileName, double progress) {
        print('FILE fileName HAS PROGRESS $progress');
    },
    onDownloadCompleted: (path) {
        final File file = File(path);
        //This will be the path of the downloaded file
    });
```

or you can get the downloaded file after completion using

```
final File? file = await FileDownloader.downloadFile(
    url: "https://tinypng.com/images/social/developer-api.jpg",
    name: "ANOTHER PANDA.jpg");

print('FILE: ${file?.path}');
```

please if you found any issue or bug, don't hesitate opening a bug in github issues section, will be glad to help solving it